# Mindfulness of Breathing vs Mindfulness with Breathing

Tags: mindfulness

I just read somewhere by Dhammadhatu's posts that it is Mindfulness with Breathing. Can someone explain the difference? So I don't pay attention to the in-and-out breaths? I'm now quite confused. Sati means to keep something in mind and now in the case of Anapanasatti the breath is something which must be held in mind as well as the other three objects, correct?